# Textfield contraint type isnot working well

Tags: codenameone

I have a a textfield alongside a textArea, one is asking for phn no. (so I used NUMERIC contraint type) and other is for remarks which is a normal one. As I go from phn no textfield to other one, it still shows number keyboard. How to make it a normal alphabetical keyboard?

check the video here:
https://youtu.be/skn-WvYcStw

```
TextField emergencyNoField = new TextField();
emergencyNoField.setHint("Emergency No. ");
emergencyNoField.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);

TextArea remarksArea = new TextArea();
remarksArea.setUIID("TextField");
remarksArea.setConstraint(TextField.NON_PREDICTIVE);
remarksArea.setHint("  Remarks");
```

Comment: Try textfield.setQwertyDevice(true) function

Comment: Its java codenameone plugin... the function is not available here

Comment: Actually `setQwertyDevice` is a Codename One method but it's designed for devices with physical keyboards not for this case. It seems like our text field logic gets confused when going back and forth between the two fields in a specific way. Can you please file this as an issue and I'll assign it?

Comment: done... https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2310